# Simplifying and evaluating $\cot 70^\circ+4\cos 70^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to simplify and evaluate this :

$$\cot 70^\circ+4\cos 70^\circ$$

On evaluating it, the answer comes out to be $1.732$, or $\sqrt 3$ .

I tried to get everything in $\sin$ and $\cos$, but it doesn't go any further. Any hints?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: to show that the square of this equals 3 exactly.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/find-the-value-of-displaystyle-sqrt3-cdot-cot-20-circ-4-cdot-cos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First $70=90-20$

We can express all in terms of $\cos(20)$ and use that $\frac{1}{2}=\cos(60)=4\cos^3(20)-3\cos(20)$.

Let's write $x=\cos(20), y=\sin(20)$ to write less.

So, $4x^3-3x-\frac{1}{2}=0$.

We square your expression such that we don't have to write radicals, but we can go without it too if we wanted.

$$\begin{align}
\left(\cot(70)+4\cos(70)\right)^2&=\left(\frac{\cos(90-20)+4\cos(90-20)\sin(90-20)}{\sin(90-20)}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{y+4xy}{x}\right)^2\\
&=y^2\frac{16x^2+8x+1}{x^2}\\&=??\end{align}$$

But

$$\frac{1}{x}=8x^2-6.$$

$$\begin{align}??&=(1-x^2)(16x^2+8x+1)(8x^2-6)^2\\&=-1024 x^8-512 x^7+2496 x^6+1280 x^5-1952 x^4-1056 x^3+444 x^2+288 x+36\end{align}$$

Now divide this polynomial by $4x^3-3x-1/2$, which is zero.

$$??=(-256 x^5-128 x^4+432 x^3+192 x^2-180 x-66)\cdot(4 x^3-3 x-1/2) + 3$$

The remainder gives you the value $3$.

We could have worked too with $3\cdot(70)=270-60$ to get smaller numbers in the coefficients, but well, I already wrote it with $20$. You can try this technique with $\cos(70)$ directly to check that you understood how it works.

Comment: Great method . Only one that works without prior knowledge of the answer . But I dont understand why cos(70) would have been easier ? I am getting a similar expression(x is swapped with y) for "??"

Comment: @antman It is just my guess. I didn't try it. Another thing you can do to get smaller polynomials is to use the long division before expanding the whole multiplication. In any case these are only cosmetic changes. What is important is to reduce to a single algebraic unknown and use its minimal polynomial and long division to reduce the expression and finally compute it.

Comment: Yes . This was completely a new angle to it.

Answer (score 11):

The easy way :

$$\dfrac{\cos70^\circ+4\cos70^\circ\sin70^\circ}{\sin70^\circ}  = \dfrac{\sin20^\circ+2\sin40^\circ}{\cos20^\circ} = \dfrac{\sin20^\circ+\sin40^\circ+\cos50^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}    $$

[Sum to product formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) gives :

$$\dfrac{\cos10^\circ+\cos50^\circ}{\cos20^\circ} $$

Again using the formula gives $2\cos30^\circ=\sqrt3\approx1.732$

Answer (score 6):

Multiply by $\sin70$ and you want to show $$\cos70+4\cos70\sin70=\sqrt{3}\sin70=2\sin60\sin70$$

Comment: Is this based on the assumption that the answer is known ?

Comment: Do you know formulas for $\sin\alpha\sin\beta$, and $\sin(a+b)$?  You should use those formulas.  I think it works out, but I would not have found this method without knowing your answer $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yes it works out from there . Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer which simplified it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Find the value of $\displaystyle\sqrt{3} \cdot \cot (20^{\circ}) - 4 \cdot \cos (20^{\circ}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/find-the-value-of-displaystyle-sqrt3-cdot-cot-20-circ-4-cdot-cos/318647#318647),

If $2\sin3x=-1$

$$\cot x+4\cos x=4\cos x-2\sin3x\cot x$$

$$=\dfrac{4\cos x\sin x-2\sin3x\cos x}{\sin x}$$

$$=\dfrac{2\sin2x-(\sin2x+\sin4x)}{\sin x}$$

$$=-2\cos3x\text{ as }\sin x\ne0$$

Here $x=70^\circ$

**Generalization**:

$$\sin3x=-\dfrac12\implies3x=180^\circ n+(-1)^n(-30^\circ)\text{ where $n$ is any integer}$$

$\implies x=60^\circ n+(-1)^n(-10^\circ)$  where $n\equiv-1,0,1\pmod3$

$n=-1\implies x=-50^\circ$

$n=0\implies x=-10^\circ$

$n=1\implies x=70^\circ$