# What is the value of $\cot70+4\cos70?$

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the value of $\cot70+4\cos70?$

So far I expressed $\cot70$ as $\frac{\cos70}{\sin70}$ and $4\cos70$ as $\frac{4\cos70\cdot\sin70}{\sin70}$. I then used the sine double angle formula to get: $\frac{4\cos70\cdot\sin70}{\sin70}=\frac{2\sin140}{\sin70}$ but I'm struggling to find a way to finish this.

Comment: I like Atticus's answer a lot better than the accepted answer on the other question.

Comment: @saulspatz: The identical question has been asked and answered before, therefore it should be closed as a duplicate (so that all solutions are found at one place). One can always add a better answer to the original question (however, in this case there is already a quite similar solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1202958/42969).

Comment: @MartinR I was just making a comment; I wasn't making a suggestion or taking issue with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using sum to product formulas:

$$\begin{aligned}
\cot70^\circ+4\cos 70^\circ &=\dfrac{\cos70^\circ+4\cos70^\circ\sin70^\circ}{\sin70^\circ}\\  &= \dfrac{\sin20^\circ+2\sin140^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&= \dfrac{\sin20^\circ+2\sin 40^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&= \dfrac{\sin20^\circ+\sin40^\circ+\cos50^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&= \dfrac{2\sin30^\circ\cos10^\circ+\cos50^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&= \dfrac{\cos10^\circ+\cos50^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&= \dfrac{2\cos20^\circ\cos30^\circ}{\cos20^\circ}\\
&=\sqrt{3}\\
\end{aligned}
$$